# Set ttyS0 keyboard layout

Tags: linux, terminal, keyboard-layout, tty

I have a beauty of a [serial terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBzSr.jpg), but it doesn't natively support a Dvorak keymap. Is there a way to remap this with software, or at the kernel level? It's a Wyse WY-185.